How to filter a window function w/out creating a new table first?
Disclaimer: Fairly new SQL learner here, bear with me
Here's the issue, I am taking a course on SQL and the question is to create a list of the top three customers (based on amount of orders) per state. We are working on window functions and particularly the row_number function for this question. To solve it first we need to join a customer's table (with info on state) and a sales table (info on orders). All is good until the last bit, where I am trying to only have the top 3 from each state. My postgreSql is telling my I cannot put where conditions on a window function, which makes sense b/c it computes last.
Here is my code for understanding:
select
    c.customer_id
    ,c.customer_name
    ,count(distinct s.order_id) as orders
    ,c.state
    ,row_number() over(partition by c.state order by count(distinct s.order_id) desc) as rank
from customer as c
inner join sales as s
on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
-- where rank <= 3
group by c.customer_id, c.customer_name, c.state
order by state asc
;

And here is a picture of the output:
Output
My question is how would I go about filtering my "rank" column, so that I only keep the top three from each state.
In the course the way they solve it is by creating a new table when they joined the two, and thus creating a second query on the created table that they can then do a where clause on the rank column - but to me I would like to know if it's possible to do this all in one query.
Thanks! Sorry if its a dumb question!
I tried doing a having clause instead of where (error), I tried using the top 3 function in front of my row_number() function (error), and I tried limiting to the top three (but of course it only selects three records in total, not three from each state).

Derived table (i.e. FROM clause subqeury) is the way to go. Some dbms's have a qualify clause, like a "window function having", but AFAIK Postgresql is not one of them.

Lookup subqueries or common table expressions (sometimes named "with clause").

What you described as In the course the way they solve it is or can probably be rewritten to use the already mentioned subquery or a with cte, which makes the whole thing a single query. On top of that, PostgreSQL will use you condition of rank<=3 when evaluating the window function, saving some work compared to running the whole thing unconstrained, then discarding results that don't match that condition afterwards.

Something like :
WITH 
T0 AS
(SELECT c.customer_id
       ,c.customer_name
       ,count(distinct s.order_id) as orders
       ,c.state
       ,row_number() over(partition by c.state order by count(distinct s.order_id) desc) as "rank"
 FROM   customer as c
        INNER JOIN sales as s
           ON c.customer_id = s.customer_id
 
 GROUP  BY c.customer_id, c.customer_name, c."state"
)
SELECT *
FROM   T0
WHERE  "rank" < 4
ORDER  BY "state" asc;

As @Zegarek answer you
